# Solving for current with voltage drops

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, diodes, schematics, kirchhoffs-laws

Given the following circuit:

[image]
[image]

Why is the current through the circuit 34.7mA instead of 35 mA? My thinking was that:

- The LED draws two volts, so it effectively makes the battery 7V instead of 9V.
- Voltage in = Voltage out, so 7V = 200 Ohms * 35mA

What accounts for the slight difference here (which becomes more pronounced as a calculation difference the more LEDs I add to the circuit) ? The circuit is shown here: http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5468024738676736

Also, with the circuit done in the CircuitBuilder on StackExchange (for LED I did not change any default params):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA9Ga7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104229/discussion-on-question-by-david542-solving-for-current-with-voltage-drops). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get right to the point here. I don't know the actual parameter values that your simulator is using. But it is probably using something like \$\eta=4\$ (the emission co-efficient.) You also already know about \$V_T=\frac{k\,T}{q}\$ as the thermal temperature voltage. I'm going to assume a saturation current of \$100\:\text{pA}\$ for the LED and thereby move directly to a closed solution.

The diode voltage is:

$$V_\text{D}=\eta\cdot V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)$$

Using KVL, we find the following (\$V_\text{CC}\$ is the power supply voltage):

$$V_\text{CC}-I_\text{D}\cdot R-\eta\cdot V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)=0\:\text{V}$$

That's basically it. You start with \$V_\text{CC}\$, subtract the voltage drop across the resistor, \$R\$, and then subtract the diode voltage and you should have nothing left -- just \$0\:\text{V}\$.

Let's set \$I_T=\eta\cdot \frac{V_T}{R}\$. Then:

$$I_\text{D}=I_T\cdot \operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac{I_\text{SAT}}{I_T}\cdot e^{^{\frac{\frac{V_\text{CC}}{R}+I_\text{SAT}}{I_T}}}\right)-I_\text{SAT}$$

That's how you can compute the current in the LED.

Obviously, once you have \$I_\text{D}\$ you can then compute:

$$V_\text{D}=\eta\cdot V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right)=I_T\cdot R\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{SAT}}+1\right) $$

If you need to see how I derived the equation for \$I_\text{D}\$, I can provide that derivation. I just felt I'd save you the added learning, for now.

Comment: LambertW, wow that gets tricky pretty quickly for circuit analysis!

Comment: @David542 See my answer [to your question in the math group](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3538763/323885).

Answer (score 0):

The voltage drop 2V for the LED is coarse approximation which assumes the current and that can give acceptable results in practical situations, but the small difference you noticed comes from more exact law between diode's current and voltage drop. That law is known as Shockley's equation.

User jonk has shown how applying Shockley's equation generates a transcendental equation which can be solved only by numerical iteration. Circuit analysis programs generally do that iteration.